# How to improve the precision of my π computing algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am messing with the Ramanujan Formula to create an algorithm to compute π at really high precision. I have installed a module named mpmath to easily control the precision of the calculation to be done by the computer. After running a few tests on the algorithm, I have noticed that the algorithm could only give the approximation of π up until the 15th decimal with a few minor adjustments to the code and after that, the code only outputs the same number despite placing more and more terms into it. I am wondering if you guys could give any tips on how to solve this and maybe ways how to increase the precision of the calculations and optimise the calculations. Thank you.

I apologise for my mistake. Here is the code:

```py
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import *
import math

mp.dps=500

sum = 0;
for i in range(20000):
    f1 = mpf(mpf(math.sqrt(8)) / mpf((99 ** 2)))
    f2 = mpf((math.factorial(4 * i))) * mpf((1103 + (26390 * i)))
    f3 = mpf((math.factorial(i) ** 4)) * mpf((396 ** (4 * i)))
    f4 = mpf(f2) / mpf(f3)
    sum = mpf(f4) + mpf(sum)
    if i == 19999:
        f5 = len(str(sum))
        print(f5)
        print(mpf((1 / (f1 * sum))))
```

20000 is the number of terms to be evaluated while 500 is the number of decimal places

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Nobody will be able to help with your question unless you include your code. (Please edit the question to do so.)

Comment: Show your code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: At a guess an intermediate value is placed in a normal float.  If you want more than a guess provide your code

Comment: `mpf(math.sqrt(8))` - you can't just wrap `mpf` around a float computation and expect to get a full-precision result.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you import ``mpmath`` you *don't* want to import ``math`` as well.

Comment: In the same vein as @user2357112supportsMonica's comment, sum = 0 should probably be `sum = mpf(0.)`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if I should not import math, may I ask for other ways how to put factorial and sqrt in the code? thank you!

Comment: By using the equivalent from ``mpmath``. ``math.sqrt`` => ``mpmath.sqrt``. ``math.factorial`` => ``mpmath.factorial``. And so on.

Comment: Try to sum the small terms first instead of starting with the big terms.